# How can I make a query to two different context?

Tags: linq

Hi I having some trouble with this situation I have 2 contexts one for employees and the other for Documents my problem is that I want to make a query with this 2 contexts and show only the documents whose Employees_status is diferent to A.
Hope your help .

Answer (score 2):

Unless you read all of this data into memory using Linq to Objects there is no way. You need to use a single context that covers the entities of both of those tables to make the query you want.

If you are using a repository pattern, keep in mind that the context represents the *unit of work*, so it should not be part of each individual repository but sit on top of that (i.e. pass it in as constructor dependency to your repositories).